# DI, Entity Framework, and Deferred Execution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have set up DI injection on my project, which injects an implementation of an IUnitOfWork, which has my repository and a Commit() method.  I inject this into my business layer and all is great.

```
public Business(IUnitOfWork context) {
    this.Context = context;
}

public IEnumerable<User> ExpiredUsers() {
    return this.Context.Users.Query().Where(u => u.Expired == true);
}
```

This business class is injected into my Controller

```
public class UsersController : Controller {
    public UsersController(Business business) {
        this.Business = business;
    }

    public ActionResult Home() {
        return View(new HomeViewModel(business.ExpiredUsers());
    }
}
```

Users is an IQueryable, and my business methods are transformed nicely into SQL using Entity Framework.  My problem/concern is after this method is executed, querying properties on the user object causing deferred execution.  In my case, say something in the view goes into each user's address.State.Cities, or some other property causing deferred execution and querying the database n times.

I've set up DI to have the database context (IUnitOfWork) to be once per request, using Ninject.  Since the database context is still open, I don't know how to prevent this from occurring.  I would rather the view to throw an exception; so that I can catch these issues early.  For completeness, here is my module.

```
public class Module : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<SqlUnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the address.State.Cities happening inside the View or inside the ViewModel? If it is inside the View, then the fact that views aren't compiled will force you the context to issue additional queries.

Answer (score -1):

Force the ExpiredUsers to enumerate the list by calling ToList():

```
return this.Context.Users.Query().Where(u => u.Expired == true).ToList();
```

Comment: Would be interesting too see reason for downvote - not sure how else one can prevent code that enumerates result of `ExpiredUsers` multiple times to not cause multiple query execution...

Comment: This brings the data into memory where ToList() is called, but it does not prevent the the view from causing deferred execution, at least in my case.  I'm wondering if the InRequestScope is too large and if I can limit it to the Business class.

Comment: I looked at it again - it looks like you're getting a collection of queries, which is why you're executing every time you update.  Try changing the function to actually execute the query rather than returning the query.

Comment: @Michael, sorry - I've actually read the answer wrong - it does indeed not help and deserves -1 as it does not prevent multiple queries. What you can do to improve on it is simply cache result of the ToList() and return cached value on subsequent calls to `ExpiredUsers`.